# SQL: Cast VARCHAR to BIGINT after TRIM leading characters

Tags: sql, presto

I have VARCHAR IDs but need BIGINT ids.

```
-- have: ORG1234
--need: 1234

SELECT 
    CAST(TRIM('ORG' FROM ads_solutions_advertiser_id) AS BIGINT) AS num_id
FROM 
    tab

>>>
Syntax error: mismatched input 'CAST'. Expecting: <query>
```

Followed this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_trim.asp):
`SELECT TRIM('#! ' FROM '    #SQL Tutorial!    ') AS TrimmedString;`

What's this simplest way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`trim`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html?#trim) in presto works in different way:

> Removes leading and trailing whitespace from string.

You can use [`replace`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html?#replace):

> `replace(string, search)` → `varchar`
> Removes all instances of `search` from `string`.

```sql
SELECT CAST(replace('ORG1234', 'ORG') AS BIGINT) AS num_id
```

Output:

| num_id |
| --- |
| 1234 |